# What does parameter -f mean with Linux command 'ps'?

Tags: linux

```
ps -f
```

when piped with grep, allows me to search for process names which are not visible with `ps -e`

According to the manual `-f` means

```
 Do full-format listing.  This option can be combined with many
 other UNIX-style options to add additional columns.  It also
 causes the command arguments to be printed.
```

What does full-format mean in this context & why I am able to see process names which are not visible in `ps -e`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ps(1) command shows Process Status. A process has many many fields (properties) associated, and ps(1) allow to select which of them should be displayed.

Unfortunately, ps is an old command, and very used, so it grew in many flavours of different platforms, and this is reflected in its command line usage: terminology and switches (e, -e, f, ...) are a bit (lot) messy.

Full format, long format and so on are partly misleading. Anyway, "Full format" probably means that, at some time in the past, this switch outputted all the relevant fields associated with a process. As the unix/linux systems evoluted, more fields came out, but the "Full format" has been unchanged for compatibility. So a new term ("long" format) eventually was invented to show even more (or different) field from "Full".

As for the difference from *-e* and *-f*: -e serves to *select* processes, while *-f* serves to choose what columns to display. Both of them should display the CMD column, with the name of the [command which started the] process. But it also depends on which system you are using those switches on (unix, bds, linux...).

I think the most useful feature of modern ps is the one that allows a user to select explicitly every single column to display.

Comment: Absolutly, In addition -f (by default) includes the start time & cpu usuage of the process.

Comment: Very well put. Thanks.